# Vk api как вывести фамилию,имя

Tags: android, java

vk api делаю по примеру [link text](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/tree/master/VKTestApplication/src/main/java/com/vk/vktestapp).
 Получаю ответ виде [link text](https://yadi.sk/i/2jfnsa-LW69gD)
Как вывести только фамилию,имя

Comment: Надо не из гита куски кода бездумно копипастить, а читать [документацию][1]. В которой явно сказано, что ответ приходит в виде JSON.  А уж "как на java распарсить JSON" выгугливается за полторы секунды :)

  [1]: https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую использовать [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list). [Здесь](http://goloburdin.blogspot.ru/2011/03/json-java.html) есть примеры.

Вот код для вашего случая:

```
JSONParser pars = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = pars.parse(response_vk);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject response = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) response.get("response");
    response = (JSONObject) arr.get(0);
    String last_name = response.get("last_name").toString();
    String first_name = response.get("first_name").toString();
```